# reading user input and detecting type of entry in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield

In my program, I have a JTextField reading the user input. The user is supposed to enter a number and then click a JButton to confirm the entry, but i want to have a catch where if the user does not enter a number, a pop-up appears telling the user it is an incorrect input. How would I implement something to detect whether or not the user enters a number when the JButton is clicked? if i need to give more code, let me know.

```
JButton okay = new JButton("OK");
JTextField dataEntry = new JTextfield();

okay.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){       
        firstEntry = Float.parseFloat(dataEntry.getText());
        //want to see if it's a float, if true, run the following code
        confirm = true;
        changeText();
        dataEntry.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`parseFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29) throws a `NumberFormatException` if the passed `String` does not contain a parseable `float`. You can catch this exception to detect whether the user has entered a `float`:

```
try {
  firstEntry = Float.parseFloat(dataEntry.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  // input is not a float
}
```

Another option is to use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextFloat%28%29) if you don't want to be handling exceptions:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataEntry.getText());
if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
  firstEntry = scanner.nextFloat();
} else {
  // input is not a float
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid of using catch-mechanism of exceptions to check if the value is a number  because this is a very expensive procedure in java.

It would be better if you use FormattedTextFields: [formattedtextfield](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

This needs some code but is a very elegant solution. You can also write your own formats with this concept.